# Adding custom image border to top of navigation bar

Tags: html, css, image, pseudo-element, navigationbar

I have a navigation bar that needs to look like this:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz4W2EsvOZtUNmpYd1o3VDkzQUk/view?usp=sharing

I have an image for it the "rough texture" on top of the navigation bar, but I cannot figure out how to add it with CSS to my navigation menu bar, like the mockup above.

Here is my HTML (using Wordpress for menu):

```
    <div id="nav"> 

        <div class="container">
             <div class="row">

                <div class="span12"><?php mt_menu(); ?></div>

             </div>
        </div>       

    </div>
```

Was going to try something like this in CSS:

```
    #nav::before{
         content:url('rough-texture.png');
     }
```

But that doesn't seem to give me what I want.

This is the image I'm trying to add to the top of my navigation menu:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz4W2EsvOZtUQmFSdXhtTE52Z00/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You could use two images in the background like in the following style:

```
#nav {
  height: 50px;
  background-image: url(rough-texture.png), url(rough-texture02.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 0, 50% 100%;
}
```

The second image is for the bottom edge. [Using CSS multiple backgrounds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Using_CSS_multiple_backgrounds)